# Ado JobStore use!

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net, quartz-scheduler

well i'm new in Quartz i'm following [this tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_9.html)

and i configured my scheduler instance and quartz to use this properties:

```
properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=loclahost;Initial Catalog=aleo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";

        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();
```

but what's next? i am new on C# but if someone explain to can understand :)

and my question are how i will add jobs and triggers and stuff to the database?

i also created the tables given in the Database/tables folder that comes with Quartz API
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whom it may concerns: well, i asked this question because i didn't know that Quartz.net comes with a bunch of good examples :) once you give the properties Collection as an argument to the StdSchedulerFactory method, and you get your scheduler, all you have to do is to keep working as you are on RamJobStore, and the job or triggers will be stored in the database not on the Ram Memory :) good luck!